# When I run my executable (.exe), it shows Java help menu

Tags: java, class, deployment, executable, executable-jar

I'm new to the deployment of Java programs. I'm trying to make my Java class (.class) files into executable (.exe) files. My JRE and JDK version are 1.7.0_25.

I had a source file and made it into an executable jar (.jar) with the command:

```
java cfm NameOfJar.jar manifest.txt SourceFile.class
```

When I ran the command:

```
java -jar NameOfJar.jar
```

the program ran fine. I then installed "Launch4J" and "JSmooth" for Windows and followed all directions to make an executable file. When I clicked on the executable file from Launch4J, nothing happened; when I clicked on the executable made from JSmooth, a Command Prompt window opened and closed quickly. When I ran the program through Command Prompt, this is what showed up:

```
C:\Users\Jon\Documents>NameOfExe.exe
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
        (to execute a class)
    or java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
        (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available

...more options here...

    -splash:<imagepath>
        show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
```

What did I do wrong in this process? How should I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the configuration of your wrapper, I don't think this is a java topic

Comment: @Typo do you have any idea what exactly could have caused it?